# how to get a subclass with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know how to get  myClass with $(".myClass") but the question is how do i get with jquery  ,myClass a?
I have a program like this 
HTML code

```
  <a href=#>Home</a>
  <div class="myClass">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
  </div>
```

CSS Code

```
    a{text-decoration:none}
   .myClass{
       color:#FFFF00
    }
   .myclass a{ background: #00FFFF}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
$('.myClass a'); // for all children

$('.myClass > a'); // for direct child
```

To get any attribute you can use:

```
$('.myClass > a').attr('href'); // to get href

$('.myClass > a').text(); // to get text
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.myClass a')` for all children (all `a` tags that exist within that DOM element.)

`$('.myClass > a')` for **direct** children (all `a` tags exactly 1 level below that DOM element.)

Comment: thanks i want to do something like $('.myClass >a).css("color","green") thanks very much